# how to handle Extension methods in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I really Didn't get proper Title for this question. Please correct it if its misleading.

I have a WebApi controller, where there are multiple validation check are there. Controller sample code

```
      public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
              return file.IsValid();

             //some more Functionality
             }
        }
```

Here Isvalid is a Extension method where the code is as follows

```
public static IActionResult PrepareResult(this ControllerBase controller, IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file== null)
            {
                return controller.Badrequest("No data sent");
            }
            return controller.Ok();
        }
```

**Issue:-** In current scenario , if the file is Null then Extension method will be returning `Badrequest()` & the same will be returned to the client. But if file is not null then It's going to return `Ok()` & same will be returned to the Clint, where as i have more code to execute(*i.e.//some more Functionality*).

I don't want to return `controller.Ok()`, so that for positive scenario i can continue with my remaining code.

**NB:-** i don't want to assign to any variable & check with If condition. In order to avoid if condition only i am using extension methods.

Comment: Do you want to do the check in the extension rather than in the controller action to specify the HttpStatusCode and message in a lower (service) layer of your app ? If so, I have an answer you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want to assign varaibles and avoid if condition as this is the most efficient way. You can use exception handling, though that comes with a performance cost.

```
public static void EnsureFileIsValid(this IFormFile file)
{
    if(file == null) { throw new InvalidOperationException("No data sent"); }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        file.EnsureFileIsValid();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid because, there are more then 8 conditions. Wih 8 If condition , controller looks clumsy. More over initially i was using the same approach, but later i differed from this becuase, this current check is Validation check not an Exception. Exception & validation are 2 different hings. e.g. If file is null then its should be validation message. i don't want to throw custom exception across the code.

Comment: Validation is a process by which you can tell whether data provided by the user meets integrity requirements. Exceptions are simple language objects that you can throw and catch, allowing to break from linear instruction execution. Using exceptions to handle validation errors is not a bad practice, apart from the performance cost.

Comment: I think this answer is valid regarding how your question is stated. If you think it does not solve your problem, then please edit your question, add more context as to what your are actually trying to do, and what your constraints are.

Comment: yes your approach is fine ideally. but i already crossed through this :) , so wanted something inline with Extension methods.

Comment: I had raised this query in another thread & got the extension way . Reference :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561747/how-to-throw-httpstatus-code-messages-from-service-layer-rather-then-api-contr

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a action to your method like :

```
public static IActionResult PrepareResult(this ControllerBase controller, IFormFile file, Action<IFormFile> work)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        return controller.Badrequest("No data sent");
    }
    work(file);
    return controller.Ok();
}
```

In you action, the use is :

```
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile([FromServices]IFileService fileService, IFormFile file)
    {
        return Ok(PrepareResult(file, fileService.Upload));
    }
}
```

But maybe you can consider to use validation.

In validation step, you enforce a parameter isn't null with [RequiredAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#required-attribute).

[ApiControllerAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#apicontroller-attribute) enforce the validation before the action is called. If the validation fail, then ASP.NET Core return directly BadRequest and the action isn't called.

In this example, if the parameter file is null then the action isn't called and it return BadRequest :

```
[ApiController]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile([Required]IFormFile file)
    {
        //Do something
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult UploadFileBis([Required] IFormFile file)
    {
        //Do something
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

PS : You can use [ApiControllerAttribute] at assembly level, it will be enable to all controllers in assembly :

```
[assembly: ApiController]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify conditions and define the error response in the same lower layer class, here is a solution.

First, let's create a custom exception that will hold the http status code and message to return:

```
// serialization implementation redacted
public class InfrastructureException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; }
    public InfrastructureException(HttpStatusCode code, string message) : base(message)
    {
        HttpStatusCode = code;
    }
}
```

We need a class to handle the response serialization:

```
public class ExceptionResponse
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Then create a middleware that handle exceptions:

```
public class InfrastructureExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    public InfrastructureExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        ExceptionResponse response = exception is InfrastructureException infrastructureException
            ? new ExceptionResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)infrastructureException.HttpStatusCode,
                Message = infrastructureException.Message
            }
            : new ExceptionResponse()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Message = ReasonPhrases.GetReasonPhrase(context.Response.StatusCode)
            };

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, we need to register our middleware:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // redacted
        app.UseMiddleware<InfrastructureExceptionMiddleware>();
        // redacted
    }
}
```

In the controller, we delegate the validation to the extension method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    file.IsValid();
    // now you can consider file is valid
}
```

Finally, in the extension method, we throw the exception:

```
public static void IsValid(this IFormFile file)
{
    if(file == null)
    {
        throw new InfrastructureException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No data sent");
    }

    if(...) // condition for Http NotFound
    {
        throw new InfrastructureException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Data not found");
    }

    // other validation conditions
}
```